# Perl switch/case module

Tags: perl, modules

I know Perl now has `given` and `when` to simulate switch/case statements, but these are still experimental and are not guaranteed to be in future versions.  Also there was a Switch module for Perl that existed in older versions, but it used source filtering and was considered not very good either so it went away.

Because of this, I decided to write my own module to simulate switch/case statements.

```
package Switch;

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

# Imported modules
use Carp;

# Exporter
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT = qw(switch case break);

# Variable used to break out of the switch statement
my $BREAK;

sub switch {
    my $switch = shift;
    my @cases  = @_;

    # Check that each case has a function associated with it
    if (scalar @cases % 2) {
        croak "Invalid format in switch statement";
    }

    # Initialize BREAK
    $BREAK = 0;

    # Loop through each case
    while (my ($case, $code) = splice @cases, 0, 2) {

        # Check that $code is a code reference
        if (ref $code ne 'CODE') {
            $case = ref 'ARRAY' ? join ', ', @{$case} : $case;
            croak "case($case) does not have a valid function";
        }

        # Handle the default case
        if ($case eq 'default') { $code->(); next; }

        # Handle all other cases
        for (@{$case}) {
            $code->() if $_ eq $switch;
        }

        # Exit loop if BREAK is true
        last if $BREAK;
    }
}

# Construct an array reference of cases
sub case {
    return \@_;
}

# BREAK from the switch statement
sub break {
    $BREAK = 1;
}

1;

__END__

=head1 NAME

Switch - switch statements for Perl.

=head1 VERSION

$Revision: 1.1 $

=head1 SYNOPSIS

  use Switch;

  # Define a switch variable
  $switch = 3;

  # Implement a simple switch statement
  switch($switch,
      case(1)    => sub { print "\$switch = 1\n";      break; },
      case(2, 3) => sub { print "\$switch = 2 or 3\n";        },
      case(3)    => sub { print "\$switch = 3\n";      break; },
      default    => sub { print "default\n";                  },
  );

=head1 DESCRIPTION

The Switch module is designed to implement C-style switch statements in Perl.  The provided
switch variable will be tested against each case and will execute any/all matching cases until all
cases are tested or a break is encountered.
```

***I have included some simple POD documentation that describes the usage.***

To me the syntax looks quite elegant (it was the best I could do without using some sort of source filter myself).

**What do you think?**

**What could be Improved?**

Comment: `$code->() if $_ eq $switch;` Just to clarify, you're testing for hard equality, not the possibility of a regex/range/etc? If so, a hash might be a better choice.

Comment: Yes, I am but I was thinking I may want to add regex capabilities in the future.  The way it is now a hash may be a better implementation.

Comment: My sense (perhaps incorrect) is that you could use 'eval' to combine many of these cases.

Comment: My immediate thoughts are that comments like `# Always use these`, `# Exporter`, and `# Imported modules` are just nuisances that clouds the code. The ideal is for a program to be written so that it needs no comments at all

Comment: You're right.  Those comments are probably unnecessary, but I do feel like even very well written code should be commented to an extent.  Especially when using advanced features of a language that newcomers might not recognize.

Comment: Absolutely not. You can't and shouldn't try to provide a complete tutorial to the language in every program you write. And adding comments to a well-written program will alienate people familiar with the language. Take a look at [*Code Tells You How, Comments Tell You Why*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/). I should also point out that you asked for a code review, so it's a little strange to argue with any response that you get!